# Open page on mobile device with callback script (3D secure stripe)

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, stripe-payments

I try to install stripe payment on my responsive website.

In Europe we have to use 3D Secure process after credit card verification.
3D secure is a system to prevent fraud.
We have to load this process on external page.

On desktop device we could open in iframe.
But with mobile device, we have to load on blank page.

So to launch 3D Secure I have to load this page with callback.

An idea ?

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){

      // Verify if is mobile device
      var isMobile = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 760px)"); 
      if (isMobile.matches) 
      { 
        // Mobile device => we open 3D secure process on blank page
        test_3DSECURE_page();    
      } 
      else
      {
        // Desktop device => we open 3D secure process in iframe
         $.featherlight({
          iframe: response.redirect.url,
          iframeWidth: '500',
          iframeHeight: '400',
          closeOnClick:   false,          
          closeOnEsc:     false,                 
          closeIcon:      ''            
        });
      }

          function test_3DSECURE_page()
          {
            var url="https://www.3dsecuretest.xxx";
            window.open(url,'_blank');  
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening a new window with java script is usually seen as a pop up by most browsers.  My bet is the mobile browser you are using is blocking this pop up.